# Which SQL Server edition works when adding a local database to a project?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2008-sp1, sql-server-2008-express

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1. On my PC, SQL Server 2008 Express R2 and SQL Server 2008 Compact Editions are installed. When I right click on Solution Explorer and add "Local Database", which database I am creating? Is it the non-campact or compact edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily determine this by extension of the database file you get:

- .mdf - 'non-compact' edition
- .sdf - compact edition

I don't have VS 2008 at hands, but in VS 2010 'Local Database' refers to SQL Server Compact edition database and 'Service-based database' refers to 'non-compact'. File extension will let you determine what you get in any case.